# Django error: 404 URL Page not found error

Tags: python, django

[I am getting this 404 error when I am trying to access the website using the url https://127.0.0.1:7000/nba/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1eQu.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set up your [URL patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/) in Django. You can see this from the error as it states that it tried the pattern 'admin/' and no others. 'admin/' is the default path that comes with Django. All other url paths need to be added. [Here](https://www.fullstackpython.com/django-urls-path-examples.html) are some examples. And here are the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial03/) as well.